# Shiny app is not generating the map

Tags: r, layout, shiny

I have a huge dataset but even if I use only 5 data points, my map is not being generated.  The code, which is shown below, runs well but I am just not getting the map. I am probably missing a very small point and would appreciate some help.

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)
library(data.table)

dd<- data.table(entitynum=c(400, 201, 602, 304,401),
            londd=c(42.3, 42.4, 43.5, 42.6,42.2),
            latdd=c(-71.1, -71.2, -71.3, -71.4,-71),
            DAY_WEEK=c("Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday","Thursday"))

#Set up ui
ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(title="",

#App title 
titlePanel(h3("My tool", align="left")),

#App layout
sidebarLayout(position="left",

#App sidePanel content and styles
sidebarPanel(h5("Hello", width=2),
checkboxGroupInput(inputId="InFlags", label=h4("DAYS"), 
choices=setNames(object=c("Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"),
 nm=c("Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"))),
position="left"),

#App mainPanel content and styles
 mainPanel(fluidRow(leafletOutput(outputId="lmap", width="100%",height = "100%")))

)
)
)



server <- function(input, output){


#Build leaflet map
lmap <- leaflet(data=dd)%>%
#addTiles()%>% 
#setView(lng="-71.094824",lat="42.343479",zoom=10) %>%
addProviderTiles(provider="MapQuestOpen.OSM")
fitBounds(~min(londd), ~min(latdd), ~max(londd), ~max(latdd))

 #Filter data
 datFilt <- reactive(dd[DAY_WEEK%in%input$InFlags])

#Add markers based on selected flags
observe({
 if(nrow(datFilt())==0) {
   print("Nothing selected")
   leafletProxy("lmap") %>% clearMarkerClusters()
 }
 else{
  print(paste0("Selected: ", unique(input$InFlags)))
  leafletProxy("lmap", data=datFilt()) %>%
    clearMarkerClusters() %>%
    addCircleMarkers(lng=~londd, lat=~latdd,
                     clusterOptions=markerClusterOptions(), weight=3,
                     color="#33CC33", opacity=1, fillColor="#FF9900", 
                     fillOpacity=0.8)
}
})

output$lmap <- renderLeaflet(lmap)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your `height` argument can't be a percentage.

From [the shiny website](http://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/plotOutput.html)

> Note that, for height, using "auto" or "100%" generally will not work as expected, because of how height is computed with HTML/CSS

Use something like:

```
leafletOutput(outputId="lmap", width="100%", height = 500)))
```

or

```
leafletOutput(outputId="lmap", width="100%", height = "500px")))
```

Also, your map code needs to be adjusted. The lat/lng in `setView` need to be numbers

```
lmap <- leaflet(data=dd)%>%
setView(lng=-71.094824,lat=42.343479,zoom=10) %>%
addProviderTiles(provider="MapQuestOpen.OSM")
```

Or, if you are going to use your `fitBounds`, you need a pipe `%>%`

```
lmap <- leaflet(data=dd)%>%
    #addTiles()%>% 
#    setView(lng=-71.094824,lat=42.343479,zoom=10) %>%
    addProviderTiles(provider="MapQuestOpen.OSM") %>%
  fitBounds(~min(londd), ~min(latdd), ~max(londd), ~max(latdd))
```

Comment: Thank you. I was able to fix this. It works now. Although I have another problem, When I  run this app through shiny server to be able to share it with other it is not generating maps. App is working perfectly fine when I am running on my machine. Can you suggest what might be the reason for that?

Comment: @Yatish I can't think why that would be the case. You might be better off accepting this answer,  then asking a new/separate question so that more people see it and can potentially help

Comment: Ohh. I got it. Thanks. this was helpful

Comment: glad I could help :)